# Can I exclude nested dependency?

Tags: scala, maven, sbt, ivy

Is it possible to exclude nested dependency ? Consider following dependency:

```
[info]   +-org.apache.ws.commons.axiom:axiom-dom:1.2.13
[info]   | +-commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.1
[info]   | +-org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-activation_1.1_spec:1.1
[info]   | +-org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-javamail_1.4_spec:1.7.1
[info]   | +-org.apache.ws.commons.axiom:axiom-api:1.2.13
[info]   | | +-commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.1
[info]   | | +-jaxen:jaxen:1.1.3
[info]   | | +-org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-activation_1.1_spec:1.1
[info]   | | +-org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-javamail_1.4_spec:1.7.1
[info]   | | +-org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec:1.0.1
[info]   | | +-org.apache.james:apache-mime4j-core:0.7.2
```

---

I'd like to exclude `org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec`.

Here is what I tried in `build.scala`

```
"org.apache.ws.commons.axiom" % "axiom-dom" % axiomVersion excludeAll ExclusionRule(organization = "org.apache.geronimo.specs", name = "geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec"),
```

Which didn't work. I guess another option is to make axiom-dom intransitive but it will require me to specify all remaining dependencies manually which is uncool.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [SBT manual](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Library-Management.html#Exclude+Transitive+Dependencies) you have to wrap ExclusionRule into exclude function. Like this:

```
"org.apache.ws.commons.axiom" % "axiom-dom" % axiomVersion excludeAll(ExclusionRule(organization = "org.apache.geronimo.specs", name = "geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec"))
```

or

```
"org.apache.ws.commons.axiom" % "axiom-dom" % axiomVersion exclude("org.apache.geronimo.specs", "geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec")
```

Comment: Oh I forgot to type when I was writing my question. I'm sorry. Yes, I have it in my `build.scala`. Otherwise it wouldn't compile at all.